# "use strict" in JavaScript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

According to  [this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/javascript-strict-mode/#more-804)

> Adding “use strict” as the first statement¹ in your JavaScript code
> will enforce Strict Mode over the entire

So why :

```
"use strict";
012;
```

Doesn't throw errors

while

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    012; })();
```

does ?  *(Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.)*

[John resig says nothing about it. he just says :](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/)

> Simple. Toss this at the top of a program to enable it for the whole
> script:
>
> "use strict"; Or place it within a function to turn on strict mode
> only within that context.
>
> function imStrict(){   "use strict";   // ... your code ... }

## edit :

[image]

## edit #2.

I tested the code in console.(chrome). in jsbin sample - it is working. still ,  I dont understand why it behave different in console.

Comment: What happens if you do `"use strict"; 012;` in one line?

Comment: @melpomene same. just tested that.

Comment: Well, then whatever you're using as a REPL doesn't support top-level `"use strict"`.

Comment: Don't test code in a console and expect identical behaviors.

Comment: @thesystem Except this sample , please provide a sample which wont work with console but will work in "regular mode". Cuase I didnt find any othere sample. `var g=1; .....g++.... `will be just fine.

Comment: A console is not a pure environment. Use any other strict mode example, and you'll see that it disables a global strict declaration, for example `foo="bar"` *(no declaration)*. This is not the case for application code, where it actually counts. Additionally, there are usually methods define in the console that are not available in application code. Bottom line... if you see odd behavior in the console, first verify in an actual application.

Comment: another case when use strict doesn't work I've encountered `(function() { "use strict"; var isSection1 = (id === "section1"); /* will not throw error, even through "id" is not defined */ ... many code ... if (false) { var id = "section2"; /* a-haa, it is defined here */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *does* throw an error.

```
quentin@workstation:~ # cat > tmp/foo.js
"use strict";
012; 

quentin@workstation:~ # node tmp/foo.js

/users/quentin/tmp/foo.js:2
012; 
^^^

module.js:434
  var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true);
                        ^
SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir - So either there is something weird about the place you are executing it, or there is a bug there. The problem is your tool.

Answer (score 1):

The console doesn't behave the same way as other places, try opening the following in your browser and you'll see the error re-appear without the need to wrap it in a function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>use strict</title>
        <script>
"use strict";
012;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can tell that the console is implemented differently to direct execution by typing  just `~`, `+`, etc (you'll get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`).
It is possible to reproduce similar behaviour by writing code like this directly (I won't call it *the same* because I don't know how the console is doing it)

```
example: { // labeled block
    "use strict"; // your code
    012;
} // end of block, no SyntaxError thrown for strict
```

Comment: I assumed it should provide the same result.

Comment: see my edit #2. Ill be glad to get a sample of which console doesnt behave like normal flowing code. ( except this sample).

Comment: The difference is to do with how console is implemented; for example, try typing just `~`, `+`, etc into the console and you'll get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`, this means the code is being parsed and wrapped by the console before it is executed, which is different to executing it directly.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I hope my edit sheds some more light on it for you.

Comment: thanks. however  the result in the console is 10. ( your last code). I guess console just handles that differently. ( everybody said it. nobody showed why).

Comment: @RoyiNamir that is the expected result, and is the same if you did it in a `<script>` (read "directly"). I was showing how you could quickly re-produce the console's behaviour in a `<script>`. If you want to see exactly how it works you will have to look through the source code, though.

Answer (score 0):

012 is an octal literal which is not allowed in strict mode as it is deprecated by edition 3 of ECMA-262. JavaScript 1.5 still supports that octal integer literal for backwards compatibility. and your example IS throwing an error!

you have 3 possibilities.

1. remove that octal literal
2. dont use the strict mode
3. or you can use the octal literal first, and wrap all your code in an anonymous function and restrict the strict mode to your immediately invoked Function Expression (iife):

012;

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  ... your code
})();
```

Comment: The question was "*How to throw a strict-code error (with octal literal as demonstration) with program-level `"use strict"` (demo in console)?*" Your answer is not related to that

Comment: no, that was not the question. the question was, why the given example is not throwing an error (but it is!).